# How to write an E with a circle around the middle line?

Tags: symbols

I want to type the symbol [image]

in latex. What should I do? I guess I have to define the symbol. How to do it in latex?

Comment: What is symbol for?  If latex doesn't know about it, neither will your readers.

Comment: @DDuck It might be some kind of esoteric mathematical notation, which comes up fairly regularly around here. LaTeX is good, but the ability of mathematicians to dream up obtuse symbols is nearly infinite.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Adjusting the 2nd and 4th arguments to `\stackinset` will adjust the (x,y) location of the `\circ` inset.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\Ecirc{\stackinset{r}{}{c}{-.1pt}{$\circ$}{E}}

\begin{document}

This is \Ecirc.

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you need it to work for different script styles in math mode, then the above approach can be adapted:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel}
\newcommand\Ecirc{\ThisStyle{\stackinset{r}{}{c}{-.1pt}
  {$\SavedStyle\circ$}{$\SavedStyle\mathrm{E}$}}}

\begin{document}

This is \Ecirc{} and $x^{\Ecirc}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I like the solution.

Answer (score 8):

You can play with the displacements:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Ecirc}{{\mathpalette\Ecirc@\relax}}
\newcommand{\Ecirc@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \vphantom{\mathrm{E}}%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\circ$}%
  \ooalign{%
    $\m@th#1\mathrm{E}$\cr
    \hidewidth\kern0.3\wd\z@\raisebox{0.225\ht\z@}{$\m@th#1\circ$}\hidewidth\cr
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\Ecirc\quad\scriptstyle\Ecirc$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. The solution is nice.